# PHAsset is failed to fetch

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to fetch photos from photo library in iOS app. I am using Photos framework. 
But I am getting an error while trying to do so, even if I am only doing so when I have authorisation:

> [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts
>   Code=7 "(null)""

Code that fetches assets is below:

```
    func requestAuthorization() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] (status) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                self.getAllPhotos()
            case .denied:
                break
            case .notDetermined:
                break
            case .restricted:
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private func getAllPhotos() {
        let assets: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: nil)
        // rest of the codebase
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, here is example of working code:**

```
      public enum FetchResults {
        case success(response: [PHAsset])
        case error(error: Error)
    }

    public static func fetch(_ completion: @escaping (FetchResults) -> Void) {
        guard PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized else {
            let error: NSError = NSError(domain: "PhotoLibrary Error", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No PhotoLibrary Access"])
            completion(FetchResults.error(error: error))
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: PHFetchOptions())

            if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                var assets = [PHAsset]()
                fetchResult.enumerateObjects { object, _, _ in
                    assets.insert(object, at: 0)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(FetchResults.success(response: assets))
                }
            }
        }
```